# Removing unicodes from streaming data

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I have json streaming data comming in from kafka topic...Im using spark and scala to put the DStream into a dataframe and am saving it into a hive table. There is a column with unicodes in it. Is there anyway to remove those unicodes?
When I try to save that Dataframes to hive table using the saveAsTable, I get garbage values. So, is there any way to remove those unicodes or to save those unicodes as is.?

Comment: Hive supports UTF-8. You should be more precise what is "unicode" here.

Comment: My data has /u0009 /u000d.